# How to add animation to collapsible element (shadcn)

Tags: javascript, css, radix

Shadcn has Collapible component (https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/collapsible) but there is no animation when content is revealed. How can I add animation similar to the accordion component from the same library? And what is the difference between these two components?

Answer (score 0):

to add some animation in shadcn/ui collapsible, you can open [radix UI doc here](https://www.radix-ui.com/primitives/docs/components/collapsible#animating-content-size). base on radix UI doc you have to add class `CollapsibleContent`to collapsible content

```
  <CollapsibleContent className="CollapsibleContent">
    
     /* your content here*/
      
  </CollapsibleContent>
```

after that select `CollapsibleContent` class by using CSS. do stying animation whatever you want.
if you want animation like sliding up and down elemen you can create styling like this

```
  .CollapsibleContent[data-state="open"] {
    animation: slideDown 400ms ease-out;
  }
  .CollapsibleContent[data-state="closed"] {
    animation: slideUp 400ms ease-out;
  }

  @keyframes slideDown {
    from {
      opacity: 10%;
      transform: translateY(-1rem);
    }
  }

  @keyframes slideUp {
    to {
      opacity: 10%;
      transform: translateY(-1rem);
    }
  }
```

**make sure you put this code inside of tailwind `@layer base`**

[result animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1YSm.gif)
please tell me if this work

Answer (score 0):

I created my own component to do this using the shadcnui Collapsible component as a base. I'm sure you could modify the downloaded Collapsible component yourself though if you wanted to.

Notice the `data-[state=closed]:animate-collapsible-up` and `data-[state=open]:animate-collapsible-down` in the CollapsibleContent className prop.

```
import React, { JSX, useState } from "react";
import { IconChevronRight } from "@tabler/icons-react";
import { Collapsible, CollapsibleContent, CollapsibleTrigger } from "@/components/ui/collapsible";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";

interface ExpandableContainerProps {
  title: JSX.Element | string;
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
  className?: string | null;
}

export default function ExpandableContainer({ title, children, className }: ExpandableContainerProps) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Collapsible open={isOpen} onOpenChange={setIsOpen} className={cn(className)}>
      <CollapsibleTrigger className="flex justify-between items-center w-full">
        {title}
        <IconChevronRight
          size="1rem"
          stroke={1.5}
          style={{
            transform: isOpen ? `rotate(90deg)` : "none",
          }}
        />
      </CollapsibleTrigger>
      <CollapsibleContent className="py-2 mt-2 border-t-2 transition-all data-[state=closed]:animate-collapsible-up data-[state=open]:animate-collapsible-down">
        {children}
      </CollapsibleContent>
    </Collapsible>
  );
}
```

Then just add the `collapsible-down` and `collapsible-up` animations to your tailwind.config.js file.

```
keyframes: {
    "accordion-down": {
      from: { height: 0 },
      to: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
    },
    "accordion-up": {
      from: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
      to: { height: 0 },
    },
    "collapsible-down": {
      from: { height: 0 },
      to: { height: "var(--radix-collapsible-content-height)" },
    },
    "collapsible-up": {
      from: { height: "var(--radix-collapsible-content-height)" },
      to: { height: 0 },
    },
  },
  animation: {
    "accordion-down": "accordion-down 0.2s ease-out",
    "accordion-up": "accordion-up 0.2s ease-out",
    "collapsible-down": "accordion-down 0.2s ease-out",
    "collapsible-up": "accordion-up 0.2s ease-out",
  },
```

Comment: This is close but on the way up its a little bit laggy

Comment: Also remember that when doing this you should have overflow hidden at the CollapsibleContent component... also take note that there should be no padding at CollapsibleContent as well... put all paddings in a div inside